# Help with proof about primes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that, if $p$ is a prime number, then $\sqrt p$ is irrational.

So far I have: FSOC assume $\sqrt p$ is rational where p, m, n are integers such that $\sqrt p = \frac{m}{n}$ where $n≠0$.  WLOG $(m,n)=1$. $p = \frac{m^2}{n^2}$ then $pn^2 = m^2$. Since n is an integer $p|m^2$ so $p|m$.

I do not know where to go after this or if I am going down the right path.

Comment: What is $t$ here?

Comment: If $p$ divides $m$, then $p^2$ divides $m^2$...

Comment: @VaibhavJena Sorry, I put in the wrong variables.  (q,t)=1 should be (m,n)=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your reasoning, we can set $m = ap$ with $a\in \mathbb{Z}$. So
$$pn^2 = p^2a^2$$
$$ n^2 = pa^2$$

Thus $p \mid n$, which contradicts to the fact that $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sqrt p$ is rational. Then there exist co-prime integers $m,n$ such that $\sqrt p=\frac{m}{n}$.

Then $p=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$, so $m^2=pn^2$.

This implies $m|pn^2$, but since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime we have $m|p$. Thus $m=p$ or $m=1$. Both immediately lead to contradictions.